# Protect Android App against Network Sniffing

Tags: java, android, asp.net, ssl, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit for making get/post requests to my app's web api.

I installed ssl on my server , so i can successfully connect my web api via https.

(Note : the ssl certificate is not self-signed.)

The weird thing is , you can capture get/post or other requests with this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture

Also if you use http or https it does not matters.The "Packet Capture" app can capture all web request...

*(You must install Packet Capture app's certificate on your device to work)*

The question is ,

I want to protect my app against network sniffing , how can i do that ?

*I'm using asp.net / iis 8 for web api if it matters*

Comment: You cannot protect the device itself. What you are interested in is whether other devices can see your traffic. Use https with proper certificates and they should not be able to.

Comment: I want to protect my Android app not the device.So , if i use https with my Android app ;  I can still see web requests with Packet Capture of my Android app.I just want to hide web requests of my Android app.(I want to protect my web requests from network sniffing...)

Comment: You confuse network sniffing (which looks at what happens at the cable) with intercepting operating system calls on the local device.   You cannot protect the device itself as your program MUST call the underlying operating system to do anything interesting and those calls can be redirected

Comment: I just saw you control the server you talk to.  This allows you to do whatever you want.

Comment: I don't really get it. Does the "packet capture" mentioned app hook all the ssl/encryp/decrypt system calls ? Or as the OP suggested, is it using a iist of SSL keys (so all the OP has to do is hiding his keys from finding it easily) @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your network traffic to be unreadable to others regardless of where they can look, you must encrypt and decrypt everything yourself in your own code and not rely on anything the operating system provides.  Use a suitably strong encryption scheme.

This is only open to you because you control both the server and the client.